# jq - Print leading and trailing context surrounding each match?

Tags: json, jq

Is it possible to print the leading & trailing context of a match in `jq`?

Say i have the following JSON:

```
...
[{
  "message": "Validating...",
},
{
  "message": "Validated.",
},
{
  "message": "Saving...",
},
{
  "message": "Saved.",
}]
...
```

I want to be able to match a string where `message=="Validating..."`, then get the the next `n` trailing or leading objects from the match.

With `grep`, you have the `-C` option to get the context. Is there anything similar in `jq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If objects under the array contain **only one** key-value pair each, use `index` to get the index of matching one:

```
index({message:"Validating"})
```

Otherwise:

```
map(.message == "Validating...")|index(true)
```

Or use this more efficient function:

```
def find(condition):
    label $out
    | foreach .[] as $p (-1; . + 1
        if $p | condition
        then ., break $out
        else empty end);
```

Then use this index for slicing the array:

```
# all leading
.[0:find(.message == "Validating...")]

# all trailing
.[find(.message == "Validating..."):]

# leading three
find(.message == "Validating...") as $i | .[if $i < 3 then 0 else $i - 3 end:$i]

# trailing three
find(.message == "Validating...") as $i | .[$k:$k + 4]

# etc
```